# Jinja template logics

Tags: jinja2

I am new in jinja. I used general programming language logic with jinja which is not working. Here in my code i wanted check weather if block inside loop is executed or not and if it is not executed in entire loop then show message no courses.

```
{% set p=0  %}
{% for i in range(0, browse_allcourse|length) %}
{% if browse_allcourse[i]['category']=="IT & Software" %}
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{browse_allcourse[i]['coursetitle']}}</a>
 {% set p=p+1 %}
{% endif%}

{% endfor %}
{% if p==0  %}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">No course.</a>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% set p=0  %}
{% for i in range(0, browse_allcourse|length) %}
{% if browse_allcourse[i]['category']=="IT & Software" %}
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{browse_allcourse[i]['coursetitle']}}</a>
 {% set p=p+1 %}
{% else %}
No courses
{% endif%}

{% endfor %}
{% if p==0  %}
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">No course.</a>
{% endif %}
```

The key is **{% else %}No courses{% endif%}**

Answer (score 0):

Jinja allows you to add `if` conditions in the `for` loop.

```html
{% for course in browse_allcourse if course.category == "IT & Software") %}
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{ course.coursetitle }}</a>
{% else%}
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">No course.</a>
{% endfor %}
```